# copying file from local machine to Ubuntu 12.04 returning permission denied

Tags: amazon-s3, server, ubuntu-12.04, scp

How to I grant myself permission to transfer a .crt file from my local machine to the aws ubuntu 12.04 server?

I am using the following command from my machine and receiving a `permission denied` response.

```
scp -i /Users/me/key_pair.pem /Users/me/ssl-bundle.crt ubuntu@ec2-50-150-63-20.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/etc/ssl/certs/
```

I am following [comodo's](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx) instruction. Refer to the heading **Configure your nginx Virtual Host** from the link. I have not set anything up with regards to permission as user. This is a little new to me and will appreciate further sources of information.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permission of the path on the server and transferred the file!

With reference to [File Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) , I gave the `/etc/ssl/certs/` path the "Add other write & execute" permission by this chmod command when ssh'd into the Ubuntu server:

```
sudo chmod o+wx /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Then, on my local machine, the following command copied a file on my directory and  transferred it to destination:

```
scp -i /Users/me/key_pair.pem /Users/me/ssl-bundle.crt ubuntu@ec2-50-150-63-20.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/etc/ssl/certs/
```

It is the write permission you need, and depending on your use case, use the appropriate chmod command.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to transfer files from local to ec2 (or) ec2 to local by   FileZila.
You can connect with your instance by using Filezila, then transfer files from local to server and vice-versa.

Comment: I looked into FileZila, yes it is a good solution because of its GUI. Thanks for pointing this out.